# Django migrations does not apply in production

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I'm running a django rest api inside a docker container on my local machine. I modified a model, commited the migrations and rebuild the container with docker-compose. The changes are applied correctly.

Therefore, I pulled the repository on the deployement server, and proceed to rebuild the containers. However, the migrations are not reflected inside the database.

Do you have any idea why, and how I could apply my changes ?

Here is my entrypoint for my django container.

```
#!/bin/bash

### WAITING POSTGRES START ###
RETRIES=7docker exec -it <your_backend_container_name> python manage.py showmigrations

host="postgis"
while [ "$RETRIES" -gt 0 ]; do
  echo "Waiting for postgres server, $((RETRIES--)) remaining attempts..."
  PG_STATUS="$(pg_isready -h $host -U postgres)"
  PG_EXIT=$(echo $?)
  echo "Postgres Status: $PG_EXIT - $PG_STATUS"
  if [ "$PG_EXIT" = "0" ]; then
    RETRIES=0
  else
    sleep 5 # timeout for new loop
  fi
done

# run command from CMD
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
exec "$@"
```

I tried to log into the psql container, and look manually if the modification were present. They are not. I also tried to log in into the django container and to reapply the mgirations, and it does not change anything.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is `7docker`?

Comment: Can you share the output of your script?

Comment: You say the migrations are committed to source control, which seems like a good practice.  Do you need to re-run `manage.py makemigrations` on every container startup?

Comment: I was using docker-compose

Comment: Yes indeed, the makemigrations could be deleted, as long as the migrate command is present. I did'nt write the script myself unfortunatly

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by pruning all the volume, images, and network of docker. Then I recreated the migrations and applied them

Probably, the current database schema were not the same locally and remotely, thus, the migrations were applied differently

If this happen to you, prune everything and rebuild your container, then make sure to commit and apply the migrations on the development environnement as well as on the deployment database all along the development phase.